# How to modify pip in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to modify pip, so that after each install or uninstall, my `requirements.txt` will get updated.

To do so, I have modified the `pip` file in the `bin/` of my virtual env.

`pip`:

```
#!/Users/username/ProjectEnv/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    status = main()
    if status == 0 or status is None:
        sys.argv = ['pip', 'freeze', '>', '../Project/requirements.txt']
        sys.exit(main())
```

This didn't work. I have tried printing the command line arguments and putting a breakpoint, but they didn't work as well.

`pip`:

```
#!/Users/username/ProjectEnv/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print(arg)
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    status = main()
    if status == 0 or status is None:
        sys.argv = ['pip', 'freeze', '>', '../Project/requirements.txt']
        sys.exit(main())
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `status == 0` and `status is None` .. and not just `=`? If you've used the syntax you've pasted, it's neither valid py2 or py3 code, so I don't think your code is being invoked at all.

Comment: @MatsLindh Fixed them, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `freeze` method yourself on the pip library.  It will return a generator that gives you the line-by-line output of what gets printed to the screen in `pip --freeze`.

```
from pip.operations import freeze

packages = freeze.freeze()
with open('../Project/requirements.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in packages:
        f.write(x)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Did you test it while a virtualenv is active? Because it doesn't work for me that way.

Comment: “It doesn’t work” is not helpful.  What is it doing that you don’t expect?

Comment: The additional code is not being executed at all. It is treated as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Utku Which was my comment on your actual question - if you had the syntax you showed there, and didn't get an error, you're not actually invoking the code you think you're invoking.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think so too. But `which pip` shows `/Users/username/ProjectEnv/bin/pip`. But you are right. With the first version of my code, if I did not get a syntax error, then that code is not being executed. But then how can I find which code is being executed. `which pip` is not helping me here.

Comment: @MatsLindh `pip is aliased to 'pip3'`. Facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was modifying the wrong file. I modified the `pip` in `ProjectEnv/bin/`, but that was not the file being executed when I typed, say, `pip install some_module`.

It took a while to discover this because `which pip` outputted `/Users/username/ProjectEnv/bin/pip` as well.

`type pip` has shown the truth. It outputted: `pip is aliased to 'pip3'`.

So, this is a nice example of why we should alias `which` to `type`. Or, why we should stop using `which` at all and always use `type`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off with a bash script like **`pip_with_autofreeze.sh`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
pip $@ && pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Run it with `./pip_with_autofreeze.sh install flask`, for example.

Place the script in some suitable location from your `$PATH` like `~/bin`, and them you can call it from any virtualenv you create in the future. Pip will refer to whatever the virtualenv points it to.